# angular-bootstrap how to set class for alert widget

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

I am using angular-bootstrap

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

For simple buttons, we can set the class like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
```

or use my custom class

```
class="my-cool-button"
```

But for the alert,

```
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

The color is `green`. I tried to add `class="my-alert-success"` with a `purple` `background-color`, but it's still `green`. When I remove `type="success"`, it becomes `yellow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the element `<alert/>` and overwrite the styles. 
I added a class `alert-purple`below.
**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" close="closeAlert($index)" class="alert-purple">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert-purple {
    background-color: rgb(216, 194, 216);
    border-color: purple;
    color: purple;
  }
```

[Plunkr Demo 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/xmW8oEVWTAvvRd5TDyxk?p=preview)

**UPDATE**

I just noticed. alert directive add the class as **`"alert-"+type`**.
So simply mention the type as `purple` or which one you want and create class of with same name with `alert-` in the front. Overwrite the styles as you want.

See the [Plnkr Demo 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/29Bzo4kb9NOMkKnDBpSl?p=preview). Check the JS file. I changed the type to "purple".

**JS**

```
$scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'purple', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
    { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];
```

**CSS**

```
.alert-purple {
    background-color: rgb(216, 194, 216);
    border-color: purple;
    color: purple;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```